# Gmail does not list sent items if mail sent from custom smtp server

Tags: smtp, gmail

We have our own company's smtp server.
When we send mails using the above smtp server, the mails do not list in the gmail's sent items.
The mail is sent using asp.net
What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your own SMTP server, [use the SMTP server from GMail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287). How else can Gmail know that you have send an email.

You have to supply credentials to use Google's SMTP server, so you must store the user's username and password (from Gmail).

Comment: +1 hahaha. Google is supposed to be omniscient, omnipotent and omnipresent.

Comment: We have a restriction to use our own smtp server. Can some changes be made to the smtp server so that the sent mails are recorded?

Comment: If you can configure your smtp server, to relay all mails to the gmail smtp server, using the correct username and password, then yes. But I don't think your SMTP server can handle this.